# Shell Script extracting particular path from given path

Tags: shell, awk, sed

My full path is `/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641`
and I want to extract and print only path from `pdf` directory onwards, 
i.e. `/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641`.

So how can this be achieved with sed or awk commands in shell script?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: One more quetion over here now I want to extract last file path from given path /data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641 i.e "K_EDGE1_641"  , I want to extract from given path to use it as a filename , so how can achive this?

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is bash, you need neither sed nor awk:

```sh
path='/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641'
echo "${path#*/pdf/}"
```

```
RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641
```

This cuts off `/pdf/` too, but that can be added back in manually:

```
echo "/pdf/${path#*/pdf/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done like:

```
sed -r 's#(.*)(/pdf/.*)#\2#' <<<"$yourpathvvar"
```

Testing:

```
mypath="/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641"
sed -r 's#(.*)(/pdf/.*)#\2#' <<<"$mypath"
/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641
```

Comment: @user1863300 offcourse it works - see test and try it your self. Maybe different version of sed in your system?

Answer (score 0):

with `grep`

```
$ path='/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641'
$ echo $path | grep -o '/pdf.*'
$ /pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641
```

`-o` -print only match

Answer (score 0):

`AWK` approach with string `match` and `substr` functions:

```
path='/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641'
echo "$path" | awk 'match($0, /\/pdf.*/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }'
```

The output:

```
/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641
```

---

`SED` approach:

```
path='/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641'
echo "$path" | sed -n 's/.*\(\/pdf.*\)/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

So many solutions inhere... catch one more with pure bash:

```
echo "${mypath/*pdf//pdf}"
```

Comment: Thanks, One more quetion over here now I want to extract last file path from given path /data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641 i.e "K_EDGE1_641" , I want to extract from given path to use it as a filename , so how can achive this?

Comment: @user1863300 with `basename $var`

Answer (score 0):

```
path='/data7/stmt_data16/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641'

echo "$path" |awk -F '_data16' '{print $2}'
/pdf/RL/20170202/INLAND/641/K_EDGE1_641
```

Comment: this will work only if you know that data16 will be always there. If the path contains data17 instead, will not work.

Comment: Please provide some explanation. Code only answers are usually frowned upon.